# Fingerprint sensor on Samsung Galaxy Wide 2

Tags: samsung, hardware, fingerprint

My phone, Galaxy Wide 2 (SM-J727S) is a device made for students in South Korea, and it blocks internet, wifi, mobile data, and stuff like that (maybe an irrelevant information, but anyway).

This "student" version of the Wide 2 is only sold in South Korea, and I'm not sure if you fellas could find any information about my device. (I live in South Korea, so my grammar might have some mistakes.. forgive me)

While I was researching about my device's specs on the web, I learned that it has a fingerprint sensor under the home button. But, I can't find any fingerprint unlocking option in the settings. I'm not sure why.

Did the software hide it? (The student version adds Knox Customization, and that's the part that disables the internet stuff. It doesn't show me Developer settings menu even after I did the revealing process of hammering the build number, but simply doesn't show up!)

I'm leaving some software information that might help you, and links of some spec pages that confuses me.

As far as i know, the South Korean version and US version are different in specs. Some sites says there is a finger print sensor, but some says there isn't.

**SOFTWARE INFORMATION**

1. Android 8.1.0 Oreo
2. Samsung Experience 9.5
3. Knox version 3.2 / knox api level 26 (?)

**Links**

1. https://droidchart.com/en/samsung/samsung-galaxy-wide-2-sm-j727s-3045
2. https://namu.wiki/w/%EA%B0%A4%EB%9F%AD%EC%8B%9C%20%EC%99%80%EC%9D%B4%EB%93%9C2 (use KR->Eng translation plz)
3. https://www.pdevice.com/product/samsung-galaxy-wide-2-j727s-price-specs